# WCF HTTP response headers only visible through SoapUI

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web, wcf-binding

I need to return response HTTP headers from my WCF service that runs as a windows service. What I have done so far is the following:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class HTTPResponseHeaderBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Add any binding parameters
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceDescription"></param>
        /// <param name="serviceHostBase"></param>
        /// <param name="endpoints"></param>
        /// <param name="bindingParameters"></param>
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is ensuring that the service endpoint is updated to include the response headers inspector
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceDescription"></param>
        /// <param name="serviceHostBase"></param>
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers.Count; i++)
            {
                ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers[i] as ChannelDispatcher;
                if (channelDispatcher != null)
                {
                    foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
                    {
                        HTTPResponseHeadersInspector inspector = new HTTPResponseHeadersInspector();
                        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a dispatch message inspector used to hook into the message pipeline and access properties
    /// so that we can modify the headers that are outbout with the response
    /// </summary>
    public class HTTPResponseHeadersInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        private string XContentTypeOptionsHeaderString
        {
            get
            {
                return "X-Content-Type-Options";
            }
        }

        private string XContentTypeOptionsHeaderValue
        {
            get
            {
                return "nosniff";
            }
        }

        private string CacheControlHeaderString
        {
            get
            {
                return "Cache-Control";
            }
        }

        private string CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            get
            {
                return "no-cache";
            }
        }

        private string XXSSProtectionHeaderString
        {
            get
            {
                return "X-XSS-Protection";
            }
        }

        private string XXSSProtectionHeaderValue
        {
            get
            {
                return "1; mode=block";
            }
        }

        private string XFrameOptionsHeaderString
        {
            get
            {
                return "X-Frame-Options";
            }
        }

        private string XFrameOptionsHeaderValue
        {
            get
            {
                return "SAMEORIGIN";
            }
        }

        private string ContentSecurityPolicyHeaderString
        {
            get
            {
                return "Content-Security-Policy";
            }
        }

        private string ContentSecurityPolicyHeaderValue
        {
            get
            {
                return "frame-ancestors 'none'";
            }
        }

        private string StrictTransportSecurityHeaderString
        {
            get
            {
                return "Strict-Transport-Security";
            }
        }

        private string StrictTransportSecurityHeaderValue
        {
            get
            {
                return "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This hooks into to request pipeline and allows for changing of the message and/or properties.
        /// Called after an inbound message has been received but before the message is dispatched to the intended operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request"></param>
        /// <param name="channel"></param>
        /// <param name="instanceContext"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty prop;
            if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name))
            {
                prop = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
            }
            else
            {
                prop = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, prop);
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This will handle the response headers that go out to the client
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reply"></param>
        /// <param name="correlationState"></param>
        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            HttpResponseMessageProperty prop;
            if (reply.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name))
            {
                prop = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
            }
            else
            {
                prop = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                reply.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, prop);
            }

            prop.Headers.Add(XContentTypeOptionsHeaderString, XContentTypeOptionsHeaderValue);
            prop.Headers.Add(CacheControlHeaderString, CacheControlHeaderValue);
            prop.Headers.Add(XXSSProtectionHeaderString, XXSSProtectionHeaderValue);
            prop.Headers.Add(XFrameOptionsHeaderString, XFrameOptionsHeaderValue);
            prop.Headers.Add(ContentSecurityPolicyHeaderString, ContentSecurityPolicyHeaderValue);
            prop.Headers.Add(StrictTransportSecurityHeaderString, StrictTransportSecurityHeaderValue);
        }
    }
```

When I test the WCF service through SOAPUI by invoking one of the services request, I get the response headers back, which I can see in the Raw view of the response inside the SoapUI.

The problem I have is that when I use the service's base address in a browser, the headers done come back. I've tried this with FireFox, Edge and Chrome, and the result is always the same. The http response headers don't show.

I suspect the reason is that the code that I have in place only returns the headers if a method is invoked, but using the base address, the code is not called.

How can I configure my service to return the response headers when the base address is used?

Comment: Are you doing a POST in SOAPUI? If yes, how do you test from the browser?

Comment: yes, SoapUI is issuing a POST. When I test from the browser I just enter the base address of the service (GET).

Comment: Why would GET work then? WCF services are normally invoked by POST methods. Exception might be the wonky webhttpbinding.

Comment: I'm using GET while pointing to the service's base address (e.g. http://localhost:8220/Development/servicelib/service/. That invokes my service behavior's AddBindingParameters, and I've been trying to add a behavior to the endpoint from there, but that's not working at all.